# My page does not get indexed after months

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

I went live with my website (using WordPress) about 2 months ago and almost every page is not yet Google indexed, except for 2 somewhat useless pages (ex. one is a page not yet completed showing "coming soon").

Here is what I tried:

- Send to google search console my sitemap in the format "https://yourwebsite.com/sitemap_index.xml" as copied by YOAST. The status is "Success" but with 0 discovered URLs.
- Checking single URLs with URL Inspection tool, obtaining no errors and asking for indexing without success
- Tried to insert links to other websites in my posts
- Today I also tried to publish some link, pointing to my website, on other relevant websites

Why is that? What can I do?